# Using Cell Reference in Range_String in IMPORTRANGE in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

tl;dr Need a way to substitute 'range_string' in IMPORTRANGE with cell referencing to an input field in the current sheet.

I started off with this query(working well):

```
=Query({IMPORTRANGE("URL_Y","25 July -  31 July!A16:E26")},"select Col5 where Col3 is not null order by Col5")
```

I want the formula to apply to new sheetnames in workbook Y. I tried to replace "25 July -  31 July" using cell reference by:

1. Having an input box(A1 in the current worksheet) for my friend to paste the new sheet name created in Y.
2. In cell M3, I used `=CONCATENATE(A1,"!A16:E26")` so that M3 could be referenced directly as range_string:

   ```
   =Query({IMPORTRANGE("URL",=indirect(M3))},"select Col5 where Col3 is not null order by Col5")
   ```

   but it returned:

   ```
   function INDIRECT parameter value is '25 July -  31 July!A16:E26'. It is not a valid cell/range reference.
   ```

Is it because there are no `" "` double quotation marks around the string? I tried `CHAR(34)` but it gave '"25 July -  31 July!A16:E26"', with the same error above.

It's my first time working with these and I'm having trouble allowing Apps Script to run (autoflagged as unsafe) so I'm stuck with formulae, maybe macros. Tried googling for the whole day but I'm not getting anywhere.

Otherwise, I'm open to any suggestions. How can I achieve this?
(Removed the actual URL as there are personal identifiers are found in the sheets, sorry about that!)

Comment: Remove the second equal sign (the one before the indirect function) and see if it then works?

Comment: Thanks for the swift response! Unfortunately, I've tried that too but it doesn't work. 
Interestingly, I tried to copy and paste the range_string from the original working formula into M3, then reference it, but that failed too, so im wondering if its the missing double quotation marks that's the issue. However, I still haven't found a way to include the quotation marks such that it works in the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the concatenate formula try (in M3)

```
="'"&A1&"'!A16:A89"
```

Then in the importrange try

```
=Query({IMPORTRANGE("URL", M3)},"select Col5 where Col3 is not null order by Col5")
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! It worked perfectly! Saved me from pulling out all my hair. Is there a reason why the ' ' was necessary here when it wasn't needed in the original formula for it to function? Pls have a great day ahead:)

Comment: If it wasn't needed, then =B2&"!A16:A89" should also work. When using names with spaces, single quotes should be used (at least that's what I always believed). Since you are new here, please check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).